# difference between clearing list and initializing list to null list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In this code, I am getting different outputs if I change the line from `temp=[]` to `temp.clear()`.

```
t = int(input())
arr = list()
temp = list()
while(t!=0):
    nt=int(input())
    for _ in range(0,nt):
        temp = []
        for __ in range(0,nt):
            temp.insert(__,int(input().strip(" ")))
        arr.insert(_,temp)
    t-=1 
print("\n",arr)
```

What is the difference between the.

Output:

[image]

this is the desired output that is obtained using `temp=[]`.

Comment: Where in the code shown is the line arr= []?

Comment: yeah my bad, I have corrected my question.

Comment: If you didn't reassign `temp`, instead you just cleared the existing list - then you're still referring to the same list that you previously appended to `arr`.

Comment: @jasonharper then according to your answer I have to get `[[1,2],[1,2]]`, when using `clear` command right? No, I am getting the answer as `[[1,3][1,3]]` why so?

Comment: All of the `temps` are *the same list* - whatever you've done to it most recently is what will be visible via every reference to that list (and `arr` contains two such references).